# Find similar documents/records in database

Tags: database, mongodb, elasticsearch, nosql

I have a quite big number of records currently stored in mongodb, each looks somehow like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c38d267b87d0a05d8cd4dc2"),
    "tech" : "NodeJs",
    "packagename" : "package-name",
    "packageversion" : "0.0.1",
    "total_loc" : 474,
    "total_files" : 7,
    "tecloc" : {
        "JavaScript" : 316,
        "Markdown" : 116,
        "JSON" : 42
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to find similar data record based on e.g., records which have about (+/-10%) the number of total_loc or use some of the same technologies (tecloc).

Can I somehow do this with a query against mongodb or is there a technology that fits better for what I want to do? I am fine with regenerating the data and storing it e.g., in elastic or some graph-db.

Thank you

Comment: so, you want to search all documents which late total_loc value 474 +- 10%, correct?

Comment: Yes and I want to add additional clauses e.g., I want to search for every document with total_loc 474 +- 10% and with either "JavaScript", "Markdown" or "JSON" in the tecloc array. Ideally sorted by number of matches in tecloc - so every document that contains all three "tags" is on top and so on, ...

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibility to solve this problem is to use Elasticsearch. I'm not claiming that it's the only solution you have.

On the high level - you would need to setup Elasticsearch and index your data. There are various possibilities to achieve: [mongo-connector](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector), or Logstash and [JDBC input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) or even just dumping data from MongoDB and putting it manually. No limits to do this job.

The difference I would propose initially is to make field *tecloc* - multivalued field, by replacing `{` to `[`, and adding some other fields for line of code, e.g:

```
   {
      "tech": "NodeJs",
      "packagename": "package-name",
      "packageversion": "0.0.1",
      "total_loc": 474,
      "total_files": 7,
      "tecloc": [
        {
          "name": "JavaScript",
          "loc": 316
        },
        {
          "name": "Markdown",
          "loc": 116
        },
        {
          "name": "JSON",
          "loc": 42
        }
      ]
    }
```

This data model is very trivial and obviously have some limitations, but it's already something for you to start and see how well it fits your other use cases. Later you should discover [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type as one of the possibility to mimic your data more properly.

Regarding your exact search scenario - you could search those kind of documents with a query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tecloc.name.keyword": {
              "value": "Java"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tecloc.name.keyword": {
              "value": "Markdown"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {"range": {
          "total_loc": {
            "gte": 426,
            "lte": 521
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no support for syntax with +-10% so this is something that should be calculated on the client.

On the other side, I specified that we are searching documents which **should** have Java or Markdown, which return example document as well. In this case, if I would have document with both Java **and** Markdown the score of this document will be higher.